# Mi acumulador no funciona correctamente en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucle-for, bucles, contador

Verán hace unos días se nos pidió crear un programa que al ingresar un valor entero en una variable X nos devolviera la suma de los números primos **menores** a el valor de la variable X. El código del programa que tengo me permite mostrar cuáles números **menores** a X son primos y cuáles no, sin embargo al momento de querer **acumular** el valor de solo los números primos en la variable suma el valor que arroja al final es incorrecto, he intentado de varias formas pero no han funcionado; adjunto los códigos que he realizado:

```
x = int(input("Ingrese un número: \n"))

suma=2
for i in range(3,x,2):
    print(i)
    div=0
    cont=0
    for div in range(2,i):
        mod = i%div
        print("Resto: ",mod)
        if mod == 0:
            cont+=1
    if cont==1:
        print("\n El número no es primo")
    else:
        print("\n El número es primo")
    
print("Suma de primos menores que x: ",suma)

#Este es otro código:

x = int(input("Ingrese un número: \n"))

suma=2
for i in range(3,x,2):
    print(i)
    div=0
    flag=False
    for div in range(2,i):
        mod = i%div
        if mod == 0:
            flag=True
        else:
            suma+=i
    if flag:
        print("\n El número no es primo")
    else:
        print("\n El número es primo")
    
print("Suma de primos menores que x: ",suma)
```

[image: Esta es la salida que obtengo al ejecutarlo]

Answer (score 2):

me base en tu propuesta de codigo numero dos.
Lo que sucede es que tu sumas el valor dentro del segundo for, si seguimos la logica veremos que se sumara por cada comparacion que se haga dando un valor totalmente erroneo.
Te comparto el codigo con el cambio pequeño que te propongo.

```
x = int(input("Ingrese un número: \n"))

suma=2
for i in range(3,x,2):
    print(i)
    div=0
    flag=False
    for div in range(2,i):
        mod = i%div
        if mod == 0:
            flag=True        
    if flag:
        print("\n El número no es primo")
    else:
        suma+=i
        print("\n El número es primo")
    
print("Suma de primos menores que x: ",suma)
```

Comment: Funciona a la perfección mi estimado, gracias no me había dado cuenta del pequeño error, muchísimas gracias me salvaste el pellejo

Answer (score 0):

Cuando la lógica se te complica, hay que dividir para reinar.

Primero hago una función que simplemente chequea si un número es primo:

```
def es_primo(x):
    if x > 3:
        for div in [2, *range(3, x, 2)]:
            if x % div == 0:
                return False
    return True
```

Una función bien simple de entender y usar.

Ahora, la uso:

```
x = int(input("Ingrese un número: \n"))

suma=2
for candidato in range(3,x,2):
    if es_primo(candidato):
        suma += candidato
        print(f"{candidato} es primo")
    else:
        print(f"{candidato} no es primo")

print("Suma de primos menores que x: ",suma)
```

Es básicamente lo que has escrito, reacomodado para que se vea con más claridad la lógica.

**Solución pythonesca**

Python nos ofrece maneras más concisas de expresar la misma lógica:

```
[candidato for candidato in range(3, x, 2) if es_primo(candidato)]
```

Esta expresión produce una lista de números primos menores que `x`. Teniendo una lista, puedo decir `sum(lista)` para obtener el total.

La solución queda asi:

```
x = int(input("Ingrese un número: \n"))

suma = sum([candidato for candidato in range(3, x, 2) if es_primo(candidato)]) + 2

print("Suma de primos menores que x: ",suma)
```

Comment: Lo he probado pero el resultado arroja a 9 y 21 como primos y supongo que si lo pruebo con otros algo similar ocurrirá, la verdad no entiendo muy bien por qué los toma... De todas maneras muchas gracias por la aclaración jajaja estaba colgado rompiéndome el coco xD

Comment: @Dan-code-str. Qué vergüenza. Gracias por señalar el error.